# How do i properly daisy chain two motor drivers that both provide power to the Pi zero-w?

Tags: power, i2c, pi-zero-w, dc-motor

I am using two [waveshare dual motor drivers](https://www.waveshare.com/motor-driver-hat.htm) to drive a total of 3 motors with room for another one. The HATs can be placed on top of each other as they have adjustable i2c addresses. I am planning on powering the motors with a 3 cell Li-Po, but after i connected the power to the HAT I noticed that the Pi was also receiving power. Apparently the HATs aslo include a 5V regulator and I now don't know if it is safe to daisy chain both of them to the Pi.

Comment: You need to ask the manufacturer (presumably waveshare).

Comment: Well, if your external Lipo x 3 = 11.1V for (12V? - Note 1) motors is also stepping down to 5V to power the Rpi, then I think it is designed this way: you no longer need the original 5V power for the Rpi, otherwise the two 5V powers for Rpi will fight and fry you Rpi. And in case your motors are also using 5V, then all is fine, one Lipo power bank stepping down to 5V for everybody. Good luck and cheers.